# Refresh a div when a user signs in via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I currently have a `<ul>` in my navigation area which holds a `<%= render :partial => "sessions/manager" %>` which basically calls another partial which depending on the users login status renders either a login form or a welcome statement.

My login section is powered by ajx and so refreshes automaticlly. Here's the code im using.

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form#sign_in').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data.success) {
      $('.user_nav').html(data.content);
    } else {
      $('.user_nav').prepend(data.errors.join('<br />'));
    }
  });

});
```

Now I want another div on my page containing various links to either hide or show depending on the users logged in status.

Currently my code is this.

```
<% if(signed_in?) %>
  <li><%= link_to "Clients", "/clients"  %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Jobs", "/jobs"  %></li> 
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

However, this doesn't work how id like. The links don't show at first which is cool BUT the links don't show again when im signed in... unless I do a full page refresh.

How can I ajax-ify this section?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to put the `div`s on the page and then set toggle their visibility with javascript.

Put this in your code:

```
<li class="login-show" <%= signed_in? ? "" : "style='display:none'" %> >
  <%= link_to "Clients", "/clients"  %>
</li>
<li class="login-show" <%= signed_in? ? "" : "style='display:none'" %> >
  <%= link_to "Jobs", "/jobs"  %>
</li>
```

And then this is your js:

```
 $('form#sign_in').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data.success) {
      $('.user_nav').html(data.content);
      // show the li items hidden from non-logged in users
      $('.login-show').show();
    } else {
      $('.user_nav').prepend(data.errors.join('<br />'));
    }
  });
});
```

That should work. but to keep things really tidy, I would move this junk:

```
<%= logged_in? "" : "style='display:none'" %>
```

into a helper method

Comment: thanks for the tip! But im now getting this error application.html.erb:41: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...uffer.append= ( logged_in? "" : "style='display:none'" );@ou.

Comment: Now receiving this error - undefined method `logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x00000127f942f0>:0x00000127b946a0>

Comment: That is your method, I guess you called it `signed_in?`. I have edited my answer again. But you should try to understand it rather than just copy and paste...